# prepareForSegue not called in TabViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have a UITabViewController that is responsible for managing multiple views (and navigation controllers). The views were connected in Storyboard by Ctrl clicking the UITabViewController and selecting "relationship segue" to the other views.

Problem is, the prepareForSegue is not firing at all in the UITabViewController. Nothing else was touched in code. NSLog does not output upon switching views by clicking on the tab bar.

**CustomTabViewController.m**

```
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    NSLog(@"Here..");
    NSLog(@"%@", [segue destinationViewController]);
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you meant `UITabBarController` instead of `UITabViewController`, clicking on a `UITabBarItem` to switch views will not fire `prepareForSegue:sender:`. However, it will cause `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` to fire in your `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, so you can use that to perform any actions you wished to perform in `prepareForSegue:sender:`. If you want to reference the view controller that you're navigating to, instead of `[segue destinationViewController]`, you can just reference the `viewController` parameter directly.

Comment: this answer actually provides useful content: after setting up `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, I was able to implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` and do my initialization there.

Answer (score 2):

Tab bar controllers (UITabBarController objects) do not segue to the view controllers that are contained in their tabs.

As far as I know there is no such thing as a UITabViewController. It pays to use the correct class names when posting a question. At first I misread your question, and thought it said "UITableViewController".(So did @MatteoGobbi, it seems)

Comment: Yes, in fact after i correct my answer in the comment saying the same thing that you then write here.

Comment: I do see why you would think that the links to the tabs in a tab bar controller are segues. They look like segues, and when you embed a child view controller in a parent you link it using an "embed" segue, but a "relationship" link is not a segue, and does not cause your prepareForSegue method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that when an user tap on the cell, is opened a new `viewController`, you have to connect to that new `viewController` in the storyboard the `UITableViewCell`, and not the `UITableViewController`.

In your case now, you should launch manually the `performSegue` from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method because probably you have connected to the storyboard the `UITableViewController`.

**EDIT:**

I read now that you mean `UITabViewController` so i commented below:

In this case there aren't segue..a `UITabViewController` is initializated with a set of Controller..so when you click on the tab, no segue will be called.

Comment: There's no tables involved. The storyboard is connecting a TAB view controller to a navigation view, which is then connected to a regular view.

I'd like the prepareForSegue to fire when I click on different tabs.

Comment: When you click on different tabs!? in that case there aren't segue..a tabviewcontroller is initializated with a set of Controller..so when you click on the tab, no segue will be called.